# Sql Server Pivot Dinamica

Tags: sql-server

tengo un problema y no se resolverlo

tengo una tabla con esta estructura. Los dos campos son string. Ejemplo

```
Articulo     Año
aaa          2003
bbb          2003
aaa          2004
bbb          2004
ccc          2004
aaa          2005
ccc          2005
```

se puede hacer una pivot para que quede asi?

```
2003   2004    2005
aaa    aaa     aaa
bbb    bbb     
       ccc     cccc
```

Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La respuesta corta es "sí, se puede", pero me imagino que también te gustaría saber cómo hacerlo.

Un problema a considerar es que no es simplemente un pivot dinámico lo que necesitas, sino que necesitas además que los resultados aparezcan en orden dependiendo del artículo al que corresponde el dato. Por esto, tendrás que usar `CROSS JOIN`, además de `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cols += STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Año)
                       FROM #TuTabla
                       GROUP BY Año
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @cols + '
  FROM (SELECT z.Articulo, y.Año, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY y.Año ORDER BY x.Articulo) RN
        FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT articulo
                FROM #TuTabla) x
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Año
                    FROM #TuTabla) y
        LEFT JOIN #TuTabla z
            ON x.Articulo = z.Articulo
            AND y.Año = z.Año
  ) AS d
  PIVOT (MIN([Articulo]) FOR [Año] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

El resultado es:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ 2003 ║ 2004 ║ 2005 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ aaa  ║ aaa  ║ aaa  ║
║ bbb  ║ bbb  ║ NULL ║
║ NULL ║ ccc  ║ ccc  ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

En caso que quieras el resultado como explicas en tu comentario, el código es bastante más sencillo:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @cols += STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Año)
                       FROM #TuTabla
                       GROUP BY Año
                       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @cols + '
  FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Año ORDER BY Articulo) RN
        FROM #TuTabla) AS d
  PIVOT (MIN([Articulo]) FOR [Año] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

El resultado en este caso es:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ 2003 ║ 2004 ║ 2005 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ aaa  ║ aaa  ║ aaa  ║
║ bbb  ║ bbb  ║ ccc  ║
║ NULL ║ ccc  ║ NULL ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Gracias Lamak. muy bueno.... Aprovecho para preguntarte, en el ejemplo planteado, la columna 2005, el valor ccc podría ocupar la segunda fila?

Comment: @IcuScc sí, claro; de hecho tuve que darme una complicación extra para que apareciera de esta forma (que es como lo mostraste en la pregunta)

Comment: buenas tardes. Si pero al ponerlo en practica me he dado cuenta que es mejor ocultar los null del medio. podrías facilitar como hacerlo? todaví me cuesta terminar de entender tu codigo... gracias

Comment: @IcuScc ok, actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Genial, que grande eres @Lamak....

Comment: me sirvio este ejemplo de hecho, pero si quisiera agregar aun lado del año no otra columna ? que me la prsente

Comment: como puedo hacer esta query que pis @Lamak pero sin usar store procedure me afecta en mi codigo de aplicacion porque no puedo usar esas instruciones hay otra forma?