# Crear Pivot Dinamico en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

tengo la siguiente consulta espero puedan ayudarme,

```
create view Pruebaa
as
select Caja.CodigoEmpacador,caja.NumPresentacion,Empacador.Nombre, Fecha,count(Cantidad) as CajaXPresentacion
 from Empacador inner join 
(Caja inner join Presentacion on Caja.NumPresentacion =Presentacion.NumPresentacion )on 
Empacador.CodigoEmpacador =Caja.CodigoEmpacador group by Caja.CodigoEmpacador,caja.NumPresentacion,
Empacador.Nombre,Fecha,Cantidad
go
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Realice un pivot estatico de la se siguiente manera:

select*from Pruebaa pivot(sum(CajaXPresentacion) for 
NumPresentacion in ([4],[6],[10],[11]))as Total order by Fecha desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por el momento tengo de alta las presentaciones 4,6,10,11 pero pueden agregar más y con decimales porque son unidades en peso(kg), es decir pueden agregarse de 11.3, 6.5, etc, mi pregunta es, ¿Como puedo hacer el pivot de manera dinámica y que me quede de 4,6,10,11,11.3,6.5 ........hasta n?

Comment: holi, yo tuve un problema similar con el famoso pivot del mal, te dejo aquí me pregunta por si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197693/problemas-con-pivot-y-join-sql-server

Comment: Más bien lo que buscas es esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131725/sql-server-pivot-dinamica. El pivot no es dinámico, por que las consultas SQL no son dinámicas. La única forma, es hacer dinamica la construcción de la query y recién ahí ejecutarla.